# How to compile the 3 or 4 objects to Siebel Repository using Batch script or shell script command.

Tags: shell, batch-file, siebel

Need commands to compile the 3 or 4 or some objects to Siebel Repository using Batch script or shell script command.

Comment: `Echo %question%|Find /I "need">Nul&&If %SentenceCount% Equ 1 GoTo OffTopic`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Christmas gifts are only for those who deserve them!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/UsingTools/compile_test_trouble7.html#wp1028071 took me like 15 seconds and I don't even know what Siebel is.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done from command line. Only full compiles can be triggered. Try raising an SR on Oracle support.